# Why isn't my html file being loaded with express.static?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

File structure:

```
- simulated-selves
  - client
    - directives
      - Statement
        - statement.directive.html
  - lib
  - server
    - app.js
  - index.html
```

I have:

```
app.use(express.static('client'));
app.use(express.static('lib'));
```

My assets that I'm loading in `index.html` are being loaded properly.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='assets/app.css' />
<script src='angular.js'></script>
<script src='app.js'></script>
<script src='controllers/main.controller.js'></script>
<script src='directives/Statement/statement.directive.js'></script>
<script src='providers/statement.factory.js'></script>
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

Why is this? `statement.directive.html` is nested within the `client` folder, which is being dealt with by `express.static`. I know it's not nested directly underneath `client`, but neither are a bunch of my other assets that are being loaded properly. The only difference I see is using `<script>`/`<link/>` vs. an HTTP request. If that's the problem, I'm not sure how I'd get around it other than setting up an endpoint for each asset, which seems very excessive.

Side question: is it bad to serve the `lib` folder via `express.static`? I wouldn't think so because they're all publicly accessible. I'm not sure how else I'd be able to serve the files in that folder without writing explicit GET endpoints for each one.

EDIT: My `png` files aren't being served either. They're under `client > assets > images`.

Comment: At first glance I would assume it's a relative path issue. Try changing your references to start with a forward slash, making the reference root relative. Then write the path as though you are navigating from your site root to the file. Ex: `/client/directives/Statement/statement.directive.js`. If that works then you know you have a relative path issue. And no, it's not bad to serve libs with a static server middleware.

Comment: @Chev doing what you said led to `404`s.

Comment: If you have a git repo I can clone, I'd be happy to help debug the issue.

Comment: @Chev Thank you! - https://github.com/adamzerner/simulated-selves/tree/serve_static_assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider: `app.use(express.static('client'));`.

Part one is that it's a call to [app.use](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) with one argument. Which basically means that the callback argument passed in to it will be executed for every request to the app.

Part two is that it passes in `express.static('client')`. Which basically says:

> When we get a request to `/foo/bar.ext`, we're going to check if `/client/foo/bar.ext` exists. If it does, we'll serve it. If not, we won't.

I happened to have been making the request to

```
/client/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
```

So it'll look to see if

```
/client/client/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
```

exists, and if so it'd serve it. But it obviously doesn't exist. I fixed the problem by making the request to

```
/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
```

---

As for serving libs with `express.static`:

> And no, it's not bad to serve libs with a static server middleware
>
> -[Chev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496288/why-isnt-my-html-file-being-loaded-with-express-static/31573609#comment50956544_31496288)