# karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor not setting the path properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, ng-html2js

I'm testing my `statement` directive. It has a `templateUrl` of:

```
/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
```

My app's file structure:

```
- tango
  - client
    - directives
      - Statement
        - statement.directive.html
  - server
  - test
```

I'm using Node + Express on the backend and have `app.use(express.static('client'));`. [So](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496288/why-isnt-my-html-file-being-loaded-with-express-static) the server will see the request for `/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html` and find it under the `client` folder.

Previously I wasn't serving static files and had:

```
templateUrl: /client/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
```

---

At this point, my tests were running fine. However, now that I'm serving things under `client` statically and and have updated the `templateUrl` accordingly, my tests are failing. This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (/Users/azerner/code/tango/test/lib/angular-mocks.js:1211:9)
    at sendReq (/Users/azerner/code/tango/lib/angular.js:10335:9)
    at serverRequest (/Users/azerner/code/tango/lib/angular.js:10047:16)
    at processQueue (/Users/azerner/code/tango/lib/angular.js:14569:28)
    at /Users/azerner/code/tango/lib/angular.js:14585:27
    at Scope.$eval (/Users/azerner/code/tango/lib/angular.js:15848:28)
    at Scope.$digest (/Users/azerner/code/tango/lib/angular.js:15659:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/azerner/code/tango/test/unit/directives/statement.directive.js:18:11)
    at Object.invoke (/Users/azerner/code/tango/lib/angular.js:4452:17)
    at Object.workFn (/Users/azerner/code/tango/test/lib/angular-mocks.js:2420:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/azerner/code/tango/test/lib/angular-mocks.js:2391:25)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/Users/azerner/code/tango/test/unit/directives/statement.directive.js:7:14)
    at /Users/azerner/code/tango/test/unit/directives/statement.directive.js:1:1
TypeError: Cannot read property 'vm' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/azerner/code/tango/test/unit/directives/statement.directive.js:22:22)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'statement' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/azerner/code/tango/test/unit/directives/statement.directive.js:27:14)
```

I'm using [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor). In `karma.conf.js` I have:

```
files: [
  'lib/jquery.js',
  'lib/angular.js',
  'lib/angular-ui-router.min.js',
  'test/lib/angular-mocks.js',
  'client/**/*.html',
  'client/**/*.js',
  'test/unit/**/*.js'
],

ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  moduleName: 'templates',
  cacheIdFromPath: function(filepath) {
    console.log(filepath);
    return filepath;
  },
  stripPrefix: 'client'
},
```

---

It's logging out:

```
client/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
client/templates/login.html
client/templates/signup.html
client/templates/home.html
client/templates/tango.html
```

And I'm stripping the `client` prefix. So I'd think that it should set a key of

```
/directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
```

in my `$templateCache`, and thus the

```
GET /directives/Statement/statement.directive.html
```

request should be "intercepted"(?) by `$templateCache` and this shouldn't be a problem.

---

What is the problem, and how could I fix it?